# not-null property references a null or transient value Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am creating a inventory management system in spring boot.while i creating a application  i ran into the problem with i attached below. what i tried so far i attached below.ItemController and
entity,repo,sevices below of item

```
   org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.example.crud.entity.Item.itemname
```

**ItemController**

```
 public ResponseEntity<StandardResponse> saveItem(@RequestBody ItemSaveDTO itemSaveDTO)
    {
        String id = itemService.addItem(itemSaveDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<StandardResponse>(
                new StandardResponse(
                        201,id + "item successfully" , id
                ), HttpStatus.CREATED
        );
    }
```

**Item**

```
public class Item
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id", length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int itemid;

    @Column(name = "item_name", length = 100,nullable = false)
    private String itemname;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "mesuring_unit", length = 100,nullable = false)
    private MesuringUnitType measuringUnit;

    @Column(name = "balance_qty", length = 100,nullable = false)
     private double balanceQty;

    @Column(name = "supplier_price", length = 100,nullable = false)
    private double supplierprice;

    @Column(name = "active", columnDefinition = "TINYINT default 1")
    private  boolean active;
}
```

**ItemRepo**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface ItemRepo extends JpaRepository<Item,Integer> {

}
```

**ItemService**

```
public interface ItemService  {
    String addItem(ItemSaveDTO itemSaveDTO);
}
```

**ItemServiceIMPL**

```
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepo itemRepo;
    @Autowired
    private ItemMapper itemMapper;

    @Override
   public String addItem(ItemSaveDTO itemSaveDTO) {

       Item item = itemMapper.RequestDtoToEntity(itemSaveDTO);
        item.setActive(true);
        if(!itemRepo.existsById(item.getItemid()))
        {
           return itemRepo.save(item).getItemname();
        }
        else
       {
            System.out.println("already in database");
           return null;
        }

   }
```

**ItemMapper**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ItemMapper {
    Item RequestDtoToEntity(ItemSaveDTO itemSaveDTO);

}
```

**StandardResponse**

```
public class StandardResponse {

    private int code;
    private String message;
    private Object data;
}
```

Comment: 1. Remove `@Repository` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` from `ItemRepo` those aren't needed. Seems to me you are "following" a tutorial and you decided to use Spring Boot 3 instead of Spring Boot 2, while copy/pasting code you got errors and decided to add `persistence-api` as a dependency. Remove that dependency and fix the compilation erros by using `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence` imports on `Item` make sure that there is an `@Entity` as well.

Comment: can you write the code help me to more clarification

Comment: No as the code you already have, it is just remove dependency and replace the `javax.persistence` with `jakarta.persistence`.

Comment: sir i removed Repository and EnableJpaRepositories from item repo but still displayed same error

Comment: after correct the error i run into the code i got the error i attached above

Comment: You really should read. Remove the `persistence-api` dependency you have **AND** fix the imports to be the proper ones. Please include your **full `Item` entity and `pom.xml`/`build.gradle`**.

Comment: ya  now that error has been solve. new error display after i added the data via postman not-null property references a null or transient value

Comment: Don't rewrite the question when the original part has been solved, instead ask a new one.